# Removing grid lines in subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a subplot (boxplot) which looks like the following:

[image]

Is it possible to remove the grid lines in the plot?

Cheers :)

Comment: what is your code to generate the plots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grid lines can be toggled off/on by calling `ax.xaxis.grid()` or you can turn them off in the rCParams ahead of time with something like `mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False`